# Zend 2 Form Select multiple : How to preselect values

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have the following form element configured and i don't know why the values are not preselected.

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'item_ids',
        'type' => 'Select',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'item_ids',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'multiple' => 'multiple',
            'value' => array('1','2'),

        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Items',
            'label_attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label',
            ),
            'value_options' => array(
                '1' =>'Item 1',
                '2' =>'Item 2',
                '3' =>'Item 3'
            ),

        )
    ));
```

I want that the "Item 1" and "Item 2" are preselected.

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

**#### Update ####**

Found something like that in the documentation, i will give it a try :

```
'value_options' => array(
           array(
               'value' => '1',
               'label' => 'Orange',
               'selected' => true,
           ),
           array(
               'value' => '2',
               'label' => 'Lemon',
           ),
       ),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set form values like :

```
$form->getElement('selector')->setValue('val');
```

or

```
$form->setDefaults(array( 
    'selector' => 'val' 
));
```

Comment: The "->setValue('val);" should be the same as 'value' => array('1','2'), ? Any arguments why mine is wrong and your is right ? Can't test it at the moment :).

Comment: Since you mentioned preselected values, it can help you do that, let me know if it works

Comment: If you have a multiselect you can preselect multiple values with: 
$form->getElement('selector')->setValue(array('val1','val2'));

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the Update of my first post, I found something that seemed to be the right way.

I tested it and this is the solution :

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'item_ids',
    'type' => 'Select',
    'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'item_ids',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'multiple' => 'multiple',

    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Items',
        'label_attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label',
        ),
    'value_options' => array(
           array(
               'value' => '1',
               'label' => 'Item 1',
               'selected' => true,
           ),
           array(
               'value' => '2',
               'label' => 'Item 2',
            'selected' => true,
           ),
           array(
               'value' => '3',
               'label' => 'Item 3',
           ),
           ),

    )
));
```